# Quick way to find a true boolean, given several boolean variables?

Tags: python

Let's say you have 10 variables, one of which will be true and the others will be false. Other than having a ton of if/elif statements, is there a better way to find which variable is true and then do "something" based on which variable was true? Each "something" will be different depending on which variable is true.

Comment: So... you want to implement an exclusive decision tree without using if/elif? Why???

Comment: I was just wondering if there was any better way to do it. Is having a large number of if/elif lines the best way to do it?

Comment: Are all of the "somethings" similar enough that you can represent them as a function? If you need ten different blocks of code for ten different variables, I don't see how you're going to improve on if/elif.

Comment: What will you do with the true variable? It can make a real difference in the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bools = [False, False, False, True, False]
# we're using constants here but you can use variables

# find first True value
whichbool = bools.index(True)

# now call a function based on that value
[func0, func1, func2, func3, func4][whichbool]()
```

If there is any possibility that there might be no `True` value, or more than one, you may want to check for this. The easiest way to check for both situations is to use the `sum()` function. `True` is 1 as an integer, so if you get any sum other than 1, there are too few or not enough `True` values in the list.

Comment: Exactly the approach I was going to describe.  I've used this repeatedly to emulate the `switch` functionality from other languages.

Comment: Who says Python doesn't use braces?

Comment: You don't really need a dict for that so I changed it to a list.

Comment: @agf Braces are only used for dicts in Python instead of the method start/end flag commonly found in other other languages, such as Java.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you could store the values in a list rather than in separate variables:

```
l = [v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10]
print l.index(True)
```

This will print `0` if `v1` is true, `1` if `v2` is true and so on.

This doesn't, however, solve the question of how to handle different behaviours for different variables. If you find `if`-`elif`-`...` objectionable, you could have a parallel list of functions to be called for each of the ten cases.

```
fns = [f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10]
fns[l.index(True)]() # call the appropriate function
```

Whether this can be considered an improvement over having a ton of `elif` blocks really depends on the amount of code associated with `f1`...`f10`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.  It'd be something like this:

```
def func1():
  print "function 1"

def func2():
  print "function 2"

def func3():
  print "function 3"

lookup = {'val1': func1, 'val2': func2, 'val3': func3}

toCall = 'val2'

lookup[toCall]()
```

This would allow you to retrieve and call a function based on the value of a variable.  Not quite identical to the other answer, but extremely similar.  This is a standard approach to emulating the `switch` statement from other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you have a number of variables, and you want to pick among them based on a condition, you should consider using a dict instead.

```
bools['a'] = False
bools['b'] = False
bools['c'] = True

for k, v in bools.iteritems():
    if v:
        print "The true variable is", k
```

With the name of the variable in hand,  you can invoke functions by name:

```
class MyHandlers(object):
    def a_is_true(self):
        # do something because of a

    def b_is_true(self):
        # do something because of b

handler = MyHandlers()
handler.getattr(k + "_is_true")()
```